# Laravel Resource Collection Rest Api Query Filter

Tags: laravel, rest, collections

I would like to add query params to my rest api. I created that in Resource Collections and now I cant find a way to add this functionality. Every tutorial is for other ways of creating api. I would like to add to endpoint /api/v1/product filtering by product code something like this: 
/api/v1/product?product_code=0208588343711. This is my code

Product Controller:

```
public function index(): ProductCollection
{
    return new ProductCollection(Product::paginate());
}
```

ProductCollection

```
class ProductCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can filter your products before passing them to the `ProductCollection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone need a answer so I did this in this way:

```
public function index(): ProductCollection
    {
        if (request()->input('product_code')){
            return new ProductCollection(Product::where('product_code', 'LIKE', request()->input('product_code'))->get());
        }
        return new ProductCollection(Product::paginate());
    }
```